# Sales Forecasting: Whole Dataset vs. 9 Stores - Seeking Modeling Advice

Tags: python, time-series

I'm working on my project, focusing on the Rossmann sales forecasting. After completing the required EDA, I'm left with 844,392 records out of the original 1,017,209, having removed 172,817 records of closed stores.

My task is to forecast sales for the upcoming 6 weeks for just 9 specific stores. I'm uncertain whether to base my analysis and model on the entirety of the 844,392 records or solely on the data pertaining to these 9 stores. My plan is to focus on the 9 stores' data ONLY. What do you suggest?

I also plan to utilize Time Series modeling, various machine learning models, and LSTM.